# Pie Chart in contribution report showing the total in last bar

Tags: contributions, reports, chart

The pie chart on contribution report summary shows the amount of contributions of each months but adds the grand total of all contributions on the last month. Strange. Is there a mean to avoid this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in 5.28.0 which was just released a couple hours ago. You're in luck!

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/report/-/issues/40